# SSRS - Multi-Column Report Dynamically Adjust Column width based on number of columns

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, format, multiple-columns

I am trying to create an SSRS multi-column report, that varies in the number of columns(2-3) depending on parameters that the user selects. When the report fills out all 3 columns it looks good and the columns fill out the entire width of the page, but when it only has 2 columns it only fills out 2/3 of the page. What I'm hoping to accomplish is if the report only has 2 columns the column width will adjust for the 2 columns being used and fill out the entire width of page, rather than take up just 2/3 of the page. Is what I'm asking possible or am I stuck with only being able to fill out 2/3 of the width?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't do this. Textbox sizes (which in turn dictate the column width) cannot be updated at runtime or via expressions.

The only way you would be able to do this is to have two versions of the report, maybe just the part that contains the tablix and have these as subreports within your main report. You can then switch visibility on/off based on your parameters.

If you go down this route, make sure your subreports are both the same width (report and body width) and make the containers for the subreports have a very small height and almost zero gap between them, this will reduce the whitespace effect you normally get.

If you need help with this approach, let me know and I'll expand this answer with a quick walkthrough as soon as I get time.